# Finding derivatives value at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

So i have function:

$$f(x)=x^{10} \ln(x+1)$$

And i need to find what value its 2016th derivative has at $x=0$.

So first I got its Taylor expansion around $x=0$

It's like this:

$$f(x)= x^{10} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}$$

So  now is it enough to just look at the 2016th coefficient which is $-\frac{1}{2016}$ since its derivative at $x=0$?

Perhaps I understand it wrongly, but want to check it somehow.

Thank you in advance for any help I may get.

Comment: is that x supposed to be there? or is it $x^{11}$

Comment: use the Leibnitz formula

Comment: @Saketh Malyala what do you mean?

Comment: $f(x)=x^{10}\ln(x+1)x=x^{11}\ln(x+1)$

Comment: Do you mean $x^{10}\cdot \ln\big((x+1)x\big)$ or $x^{10}\cdot \big(\ln(x+1)\big)\cdot x$ ?

Comment: Oh yeah i messed up, no x there

Comment: So just $x^{10}\ln(x+1)$ ?

Comment: Yeah, just that

Comment: Your series should have "$\cdot x^n$", not "$+x^n$", right? Isn't $\ln(x+1) = x-\tfrac {x^2}2 + \tfrac{x^3}3 -\cdots$?

Comment: Is it really like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Taylor expansion of $\ln(x+1)$ is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}
$$
(you have a wrong plus sign). If we multiply by $x^{10}$ we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{n+10}}{n}
$$
so the coefficient of $x^{2016}$ is when $n+10=2016$, that is, $n=2006$:
$$
\frac{(-1)^{2007}}{2006}=-\frac{1}{2006}
$$
Now, the Taylor coefficient of the $k$-th power is
$$
\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}
$$
and therefore
$$
\frac{f^{(2016)}(0)}{2016!}=-\frac{1}{2006}
$$

Comment: Yes, good post. Initial typo in OP's question, notwithstanding.

Comment: So at the end i just need to multiply both sides with $2016!$ ?

Comment: @MathIsTheWayOfLife Exactly so. Your problem was just in the shifting of the exponents.

Comment: Okay, thank you a lot.